# Need to display Gauge dashboard on home page in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, reporting, visualforce-component

Requirement :**Need to display Gauge dashboard on home page in salesforce**

I have created a visualforce page and copy the  url from inspect element and paseted in  tag for  showing gauge dashboard in home page.

but when my report count is changing then dashboard gauge is not reflecting.
Please suggest if anyone having idea to display Gauge dashboard in Home page

Comment: Have you used apex:chart & apex:gaugeSeries ?? You can reRender the apex:chart component on some event.

Answer (score 1):

See [analytics:reportChart](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) in the VisualForce Developer's Guide. Specifically, I think you'll want to look at the `cacheResults` attribute:

> A Boolean indicating whether to use cached data when displaying the chart. When the attribute is set to true, data is cached for 24 hours, but you can modify the length of time with the cacheAge attribute. If the attribute is set to false, the report is run every time the page is refreshed.

Alternatively, you could reduce the `cacheAge` (long) attribute setting such that the chart refreshes more frequently, say every 30 minutes, without having to rebuild itself every time the home page is loaded:

> The length of time that an embedded chart can cache data, in milliseconds (for example, 24 hours = 86,400,000 ms). The maximum length of time is 24 hours.

There's also the `showRefreshButton` attribute to consider which would allow a user the option to manually refresh a chart (but not the source data):

> A Boolean indicating whether to add a refresh button to the chart.

There's additional information in the VisualForce Developer's Guide on different options available for [Updating Charts with Refreshed Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_charting_refreshing_data.htm).